# Outer *ngFor slected value in inner *ngFor

Tags: angular

We are having an angular 4 application and we need to implement 1 requirement.
We had implemented *ngFor upto 3 levels below is the code snippet for it.

```
<div *ngFor="let country of Countries">
  country.name
   <div *ngFor="let state of country.States">
    state.Name
      <div *ngFor="let city of state.Cities">
         city.Name
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

We have a requirement that default cities of state should be visible and on click of any other state its respective cities should be populated in div of city

How can we achieve this in angular 4?

Comment: what have you tried to achieve this requirement so far?

Comment: Your question is unclear : from your code you want to display cities of states, and on click, display cities of state ? Please rephrase your question

Comment: for by default to get the cities of first state we have assigned parameter with index value and then used ngIf in city div to have if parameter value is equal to 0

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Are you want to implement that If someone will click on state then it's all cities will visible in div that child of state div?

```
<div *ngFor="let country of Countries">
  country.name
   <div *ngFor="let state of country.States; let i = index">
    <span (click)="showCities(i)">state.Name</span>
      <div *ngIf="i === index" *ngFor="let city of state.cities">
         city.Name
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In you component just paste following code:

```
index: number = 0;
public showCities(i){
    this.index = i;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to have this functionality of it should display cities of selected state

Comment: Thanks Sandip, it worked for me just a minor changes require to handle city count for different states